# ConnectionRefusedError socket python

Tags: python, sockets, server

i wrote simple client/server program using packet socket but get an error

Here's my code:

```
import socket
import random
import sys

def double_server(port=8080):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(('', port))
        print('Start work!')
        s.listen(5)
        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            handle_connection(conn, addr)


def handle_connection(conn, addr):
    print('Connected: ', addr)
    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            n = int(data.decode())
            res = f"{n*2}\n".encode()
            conn.send(res)

def double_client(port=8080):
    with socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', port)) as s:
        f = s.makefile(mode='rw', buffering=1, newline='\n')
        while True:
            n = random.randrange(10)
            f.write(f'{n}\n')
            print(n, f.readline().strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'server':
        double_server()

    elif sys.argv[1] == 'client':
        double_client()
```

But i got ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Thank you in advance

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you running the server at the moment you're trying to connect? Maybe you have a badly configured firewall?

Comment: edit port to 12345 and it starts working)